# How to get new customer id using customer_save_before event in observer in magento2

Tags: magento2, event-observer, frontend

I want to get id of the customer when I add new record of customer new account in `customer_save_before` event.

Id will be display before record saved in customer_entity table.

How to get id using `customer_save_before` in observer?

Please help me.

Comment: You need to retrieve customer collection  by desc and set limit 1

Comment: By increment +1 into last inserted id you may get your new ID

Comment: @Rohan incase if you creating new customer how will you get id before save?

Comment: @RonakChauhan when 100 people insert record at same time then which last id i got...there is no sufficient logic for that.

Comment: @Satish I want to add mobile number in customer_entity table and I want to check that mobile number is repeated or not before save record. If repeat then error message display and stop record save otherwise add record

Comment: Rohan Hapani, you should update ur question ... The  target of your question  and comment are not same. It make user to confusion

Comment: You should correct your question, as per your question you won't get any sufficient answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As per as your comment, you want ***validate customer  mobile no before have whenever new customer is created or record is updated***.

In this you can use your `customer_save_before` event:

and observer may be like this:

---

```
<?php
namespace Devamitbera\MobileCheck\Observer;

use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\Request\DataPersistorInterface;
use Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\AlreadyExistsException;

class ValidateMobileNo implements ObserverInterface
{

    protected $_customerCollectionFactory;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Customer\Model\ResourceModel\Customer\CollectionFactory $customerCollectionFactory,
    ) {
        $this->_customerCollectionFactory = $customerCollectionFactory;
    }


    /**
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer
     * @return void
     */
    public function execute(\Magento\Framework\Event\Observer $observer)
    {
        $customer = $observer->getCustomer();
        $customerCollection= $this->_customerCollectionFactory->create();
        $customerCollection->addAttribuTeToFilter('[YOUR_ATTRUBUTE]',$customer->getData('[YOUR_ATTRUBUTE]'));
        if ($customer->getId()) {   
            $customerCollection->addAttribuTeToFilter('entity_id',array('neq' => (int)$customer->getId()));   
         }   
         if($customerCollection->getSize()>0){
             throw new AlreadyExistsException(
                __('A customer with the same Mobile already exists .')
            );

         }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it myself but dig into Magento core files and got this solution.

Please look into this class:

**Magento\Framework\Model\ResourceModel\Db\AbstractDb**

Into the function named **saveNewObject()** around line number 762

```
 $object->setId($this->getConnection()->lastInsertId($this->getMainTable()));
```

using the **lastInsertId()** one can get the last added Id in particular table by passing the name of the table.

Hope, this will help you.